# How to make a line between specific cells in htmlTable?

Tags: r, html-table

I have managed to color cells but I also want to draw a line between the cells 3 and 3 and 8 and 9. How do I do that?

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(4,3,9,9),b=c(5,3,8,8))

## indices defining where the styles go
where <- rbind(c(2,1),c(2,2))
style <- rep(('background-color: orange'),2)

css.cell <- matrix('', nrow(df), ncol(df))
css.cell[where] <- style

library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(df, css.cell = css.cell)
```

[image]

I want it like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-bottom`:

```
style <- rep(('background-color: orange; border-bottom: 2px solid;'), 2)
```

---

## EDIT

For your other question:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(4,3,9,9),b=c(5,3,8,8),c=c(5,6,7,8))

## indices defining where the styles go
where1 <- rbind(c(2,1),c(2,2))
style1 <- rep(('background-color: orange; border-bottom: 2px solid;'), 2)
where2 <- rbind(c(2,3))
style2 <- "border-bottom: 2px solid;"

css.cell <- matrix('', nrow(df), ncol(df))
css.cell[where1] <- style1
css.cell[where2] <- style2

library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(df, css.cell = css.cell)
```

Comment: thanks! I realized I wanted to separate the lining and coloring, is it possible? see my answer to my own question :)

Comment: @user11916948 Yes, see my edit.